# Game of Life , NetLogo i Extend my neighbors to 24 cells using in-radius

Tags: netlogo

Here is the code :

```
to new_neighbor

  set my-neighbors (other patches) in-radius 2


end

to go
  ask patches
    [ set live-neighbors count my-neighbors with [living?] ]
  ;; Starting a new "ask patches" here ensures that all the patches
  ;; finish executing the first ask before any of them start executing
  ;; the second ask.  This keeps all the patches in synch with each other,
  ;; so the births and deaths at each generation all happen in lockstep.
  ask patches
    [ ifelse live-neighbors = 3
      [ cell-birth ]
      [ if live-neighbors != 2
        [ cell-death ] ] ]
  tick
end
```

Here is the error:

COUNT expected input to be an agentset but got the number 0 instead.
Error while patch 30 -31 running COUNT
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go-once'

I just want to extend my neighbors to 24 cell. Nothing else. I want program to check not first 8 cells ring but 24.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Look in the Models Library (File menu). In the Code Examples section, there is one called 'Moore & von Neumann Example'. That does exactly what you want.

For your error, there were no patches in my-neighbors. Your code doesn't include any section that actually sets the my-neighbors variable, so it's unclear why it was empty. That is, what bit of code actually calls the procedure `new_neighbor`?